# Joomla store data on session

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I'm modifying a joomla component (jQuarks) in order to achieve the wanted behaviour from the module in order to do online quiz/exams.
Basically, I want to be able to use the session variable to store the following items:

- UserId
- QuizSessionID (not the Joomla Session per se, since this is a jQarks "session")
- The quiz start time
- Last question answered page (or id, doesn't really matter, but since I'm using pages it's the best option)
- All the previously answered questions (ie, the question ID and the Answer ID)

In order to achieve this I'm using JFactory::getSession() but I'm having some doubts.

The first one is: Is the session variable the best way to store this data? If not, how or where can I store this info?
Whenever the user clicks to navigate to the next page, I want to store the answer given and add it to the previously given answers. Won't this make me have to constantly destroy and recreate the session?
If, by any chance a user needs to refresh the page, the current component behavior is to create a new quizSession thus reseting everything and storing nothing. Will the Joomla Session variable be enough to force the behavior I intend? (resuming the quizSession that te user started)

If this is the wrong approach what should I use? I'm not really versed developing for Joomla and haven't touched PHP in at least 3 years...

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advice you not to use JSession, but try User state. It is widely used in Joomla for storing pagiantion, filters vars across pages. You can find info about it [here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_user_state_variables).

The only concern I have is a page refresh. The state will not be reset on refresh and I doubt that it is possible to do with Joomla API...

And one more thing - you do not need to store UserId in the session, because you can anytime retrieve it using this simple piece of code:

```
$userId = JFactory::getUser()->id;
```

More info [here](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getUser).

Comment: I did take a look at that class but I couldn't know for sure about what happens upon a page refresh/reload. Do these persist or get reset?

Comment: It will persist. And I do not know how to reset it on page refresh.

Comment: I don't wan't to reset it on a page refresh so it should be no problem. I just want to persist data on a refresh. I can delete everything once the "quiz" is finished and written to the DB

Answer (score 1):

`SESSION` is using for temporary data. You can use it to store data if you are not afraid to lose it.

If you what to associate some data permanent use `#__user_profiles table`, like key value storage.

If you want have some analytic of it you must use your you **DB** structure.

Comment: Well, everything is getting kept on the DB so I have no problems there. The only thing worrying me is about the page refresh which should temporarily store the data before it is written in the DB, so Session seemed like a good idea.